# Mathematica input

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I just installed mathematica 8, and I am unable to input the mathematica programming language. The free-form linguistic mode works because it's connecting to the wolfram servers, but if try to plot something as simple as:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6Pi}]
```

Hit Shift-Enter, I get the message:

```
MakeExpression::boxfmt: InputForm in MakeExpression[FormBox[RowBox[{Plot,
[,RowBox[{RowBox[{<<4>>}],,,RowBox[{<<3>>}]}],]}],InputForm],InputForm] is 
not a box formatting type. A box formatting type is any member of $BoxForms. >>
```

However, if I just go to the documentation for Plot, copy and paste the same function from the documentation into my notebook, hit shift-enter, the plot shows up.

I was just following along the hands-on tutorial and ran into this problem.

Comment: I assume restarting Mathematica doesn't help?  It sounds like your installation may be broken...

Answer (score 2):

Please try clearing the cache and preferences as described in the Troubleshooting tutorial appropriate to your platform.  Search for "Troubleshooting" in the help browser.

For example (OS X):

> #### Front End Preferences
>
> Front end preferences, such as the locations of recently opened and
> saved files, are stored in a front end initialization file called
> init.m. This file is located in the directory
> ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd. If you need to reset the front end
> preferences to their default values, hold down
> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> during startup. This will cause the
> initialization file to be rebuilt automatically.
>
> #### Caches
>
> Information about your Mathematica system layout, such as the
> locations of text resource files and help files, is stored in caches.
> These caches are located in the directory
> ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/7.0/Caches.
>
> A corrupted cache may cause the front end to produce an error or quit
> immediately on startup. The most convenient way to restore the caches
> to their default values is to hold down
> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> during startup. This will cause the
> Mathematica caches and the initialization file to be rebuilt
> automatically.
>
> If you want to rebuild your caches but retain your preferences, hold
> down <kbd>Shift</kbd> during startup. This will delete and rebuild the
> cache without rebuilding your front end initialization file.

Comment: this worked for me (Holding down "Shift" button at start up)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some strange formatting issue. The cell seems to have some formatting that you can't see. Making a new cell by clicking down at the bottom and typing there should fix the problem.

Comment: I think the formatting is the issue, since if I copy and paste a Plot command from the documentation, then change the function, it correctly plots different functions. However, even if I open a brand new notebook, type in Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}], same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Open New > Package(.m)

It gives you a single textbox to type/paste in. Write this command. The formatting shouldn't pose a problem in the package mode. Hit Run package at the top.